# /forceit in Command Prompt Gives error: unknown command

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, bios, dell-inspiron

I am trying to run a BIOS update using `/forceit` command after the file name on a Dell Inspiron with a 'faulty' battery (BIOS update on Dell requires 10% battery, hence why I cannot perform this) . I keep getting the following error message:

```
error: unknown command.
```

This command should allow me to update the BIOS. Updating the BIOS is my last resort as I have tried practically everything. Is there a way to run this command?

Comment: Have you reached a solution?

Comment: this isn't even any paramter of any command native to any windows version, it's particular to some dell thing apparently, according to peter

Answer (score 4):

- Make Bootable FreeDOS USB Drive personally I used Rufus Portable.
- Copy the BIOS EXE File. Mine was 3442A14.exe for Inspiron 3542.
- Restart computer and press F12 at boot logo.
- Boot the USB Drive.
- DOS window should appear now type the first letter of the filename and then press tab or type the full name of the file followed by /Forceit
- Press Y to continue update. Update should prepare files the restart and then start updating with percent bar repeated several times and then restart to start Windows with BIOS updated.

Comment: When I try from FreeDOS (and MSDOS 6.22), I get the error message:
- Error: Unable to start a Secure Flash session.

Comment: Using a hint at https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkCentre-A-E-M-S-Series/BIOS-update-gives-me-18-Error-Unable-to-start-a-Secure-Flash/td-p/4183038 , I was able to update from A02 up to A13 successfully, and then up to the current A16.

Comment: I have a Vostro 3550 with a dead battery that would not display on the built-in LCD after installing Windows 10 (black screen, HDMI external displays worked). Only fix I found listed online was to update from BIOS A09 to A12, but my battery was dead. I tried using /forceit command line switch in Windows using an HDMI monitor and I got the same error unknown command. I made a freeDOS boot drive with Rufus and used /forceit command with the A12 BIOS update and it went through! Windows 10 now works with the built-in LCD on my Vostro 3550 with BIOS A12 thanks to you! You are my savior for the day!

Answer (score 1):

`/forceit` is not a command of its own, you need to use it as a command line parameter like `DellBIOSUpdater.exe /forceit`.

Comment: thanks for your reply.

I did use it like that.. C:\'file_path'\filename.exe /force it, however I still get the **error: command unknown**

Comment: Don't put parts of the path in 's and don't separate the words 'force' and 'it'. You need to be precise, or Windows won't know what you mean.

Comment: I'm positive I'm writing it correctly. Is it possible to update BIOS using hirens boot cd ?

Answer (score -1):

I have an Acer Aspire ES1-111 which battery cannot hold any charge, I checked battery capacity using "powercfg -energy" and it showed that the battery still has its full capacity so I guess it must be bios problem.

I downloaded the latest bios update but it showed an error "cannot continue because battery juice under 15%" or something like that.

Tried `/forceit` command parameter to no avail.

After digging deep I finally found a solution [here on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1092562/how-to-upgrade-uefi-bios-without-battery-in-acer-laptop/1106948#1106948):

> 1. Download the BIOS update from Acer site (ZHK116.EXE)
> 2. Run the downloaded file, you will get an error like "No battery" or "Low battery", stay on the error dialogue (!)
> 3. Navigate to your current users temp directory (e.g. Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Temp), there should be somewhere a
>      temporary directory containing the extracted files from the EXE file
>      (for me it was 7zS4A88.tmp)
> 4. Save the contents of that temp directory somewhere (you can then close the error dialogue, the temp files will be removed)
> 5. Open the file platform.ini with a text editor and search for the key "AC_Adapter"
> 6. Change parameter BatteryCheck from 1 to 0 or just leave it empty (this disables battery check during BIOS update preparation!), save
>      the file
> 7. Run InsydeFlash.exe in the same directory
> 8. That's it, bios update should start now

Comment: -1 see peter's answer at least he mentions that it's a parameter to a command that is  a dell thing