# How to upgrade UEFI bios without battery in Acer laptop?

Tags: boot, laptop, bios

My laptop is an Acer Aspire V5-473PG and I use Windows 10 Pro 64-bit. And my battery is already dead around 1 year. Now, when I turn on my laptop, it always shows something like this :

> “Boot media is missing, Please insert bootable media...”

But, I can boot with legacy boot mode, not UEFI. So, I think my UEFI firmware has some problem and I want to upgrade my UEFI. So, I download correct BIOS for my laptop from acer website and it contains only one executable file.

When I run that file to upgrade BIOS, it shows this and I can't upgrade:

> “Please insert system battery.”

I already searched many ways on internet, but not working. So, please anyone help me how can I upgrade my BIOS without battery.

Comment: Run the bios exe via CMD and add /forceit in the end.

Comment: I already tried as you said via CMD and also try from cmd from bootable DVD drive. But its not work. Its ask to insert system battery.

Comment: Did you add that command in the end. /forceit

Comment: yes, I did like this.

Comment: @vembutech Please help me if you have other options.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just got thorugh this "upgrade bios without battery" hell on my Acer E11.

The following worked for me:

1. Download the BIOS update from Acer site (ZHK116.EXE)
2. Run the downloaded file, you will get an error like "No battery" or "Low battery", stay on the error dialogue (!)
3. Navigate to your current users temp directory `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp`, there should be somewhere a temporary directory containing the extracted files from the EXE file (for me it was 7zS4A88.tmp)
4. Save the contents of that temp directory somewhere (you can then close the error dialogue, the temp files will be removed)
5. Open the file platform.ini with a text editor and search for the key "AC_Adapter"
6. Change parameter BatteryCheck from 1 to 0 or just leave it empty (this disables battery check during BIOS update preparation!), save the file
7. Run InsydeFlash.exe in the same directory
8. That's it, bios update should start now

Some additional notes:

- Extracting the ZHK116.EXE manually via 7zip did not work because BIOS flash file isflash.bin (ROM file) not packed, but concatenated to the end of ZHK116.EXE file
- Opening the ZHK116.EXE with 7zip and modifying the plattform.ini file out of 7zip did not work either, you cannot save the file
- Updating BIOS via a bootable USB device having a FreeDOS on it did not work getting the same "battery" error (seems that the check is also done in DOS)

Comment: For some reson after I run InsydeFlash64.exe tool it overwrites changes I've made in platforms.ini back to defaults. :(

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
WinFlash64.exe /bcp /sd /ver /cvar /v /endkey /silent/bbl /cac /cbp 30
```

to:

```
WinFlash64.exe /bcp /sd /ver /cvar /v /endkey /silent/bbl /cac /cbp 0
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had an ACER Aspire V5-571P with the same problem.

Following on from the previous answer, my *.exe file was called "VA410218.exe" and extracted to "Users//AppData/Local/Temp/7z????.tmp" directory and contained the files (Which as stated will probably get erased when the cmd window closes .. so keep it open) and copy them to somewhere useful. .

Alternatively, open the *.exe as an archive using 7-zip (or WinZip?) and extract them directly to somewhere.

There will then be your "Somewhere" directory containing:-
Launch.bat
Update.bat
BIOS.cap
cmd.exe
WinFlash32
WinFlash64
TdkLib.sys
TdkLib64.sys

(Or something similar)

The important one is Launch.Bat which actually calls the WinFlashxx program.
Edit this and look for

WinFlash32.exe /bcp /sd /ver /cvar /v /endkey /silent /bbl /cac /cbp 30 / ..

or

WinFlash64.exe /bcp /sd /ver /cvar /v /endkey /silent/bbl /cac /cbp 30 / ..

Depending on your operating system.

The switch /cbp 30 is the minimum battery level required before the program stops. Either delete this switch or change the value to something lower.

Then execute the batch file "update.bat" (as Admin) and voila. No battery checking.

This is not for the faint hearted and you must "absolutely not" lose power during the flashing process. (UPS?)

Don't blame me if it ends in tears.

PS, it did not solve my battery problem (I have gone through 4 now, some only lasted a week)

Answer (score 0):

I flash bios in my acer 5560g with dead 0% battery from antisms win8 pe livecd.
I cant flash bios from dos, because my battery lvl is there -6999%.
But in livecd it be 23%. I run win bios .exe in a few minutes later and lvl battery is 25%. I waited about 20 minutes, until the charge was 30 and safely flash bios on my notebook.
I hope that my decision can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

3.Navigate to your current users temp directory %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp, there should be somewhere a temporary directory containing the extracted files from the EXE file (for me it was 7zS4A88.tmp)

Look the biggest directory, whatever the name was.
Have several on carpet, that create confusion, don´t worry.
Works for me in a: Aspire ES1-511 good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I followed accepted answer, but files where under `C:\Windows\Temp`.
Check where the files are being decompressed, when starting the .EXE