# Getting an “unknown command” error when trying to update the BIOS on a Dell Inspiron N5110

Tags: bios, updates, dell-inspiron

I need to perform a BIOS update on a Dell Inspiron N5110 with a battery issue.

I tried to update the BIOS by executing `N5110A11.exe /forceit` in the command line, where `N5110A11.exe` is Dell's BIOS update utility, but it failed with an “unknown command” error.
The `/forceit` switch is needed because the battery issue prevents a normal update.

How can I install the BIOS update with the `/forceit` switch?

Comment: Note that im trying to update my BIOS cause my ac adapter dont charge my laptop battery, i earn that it's due to the version of BIOS, any recommandations please, i'm new at the coin , nice weekend

Comment: Please add the complete command you used to your question like `somebiosversion.exe /forceit`.

Comment: I tried this but no issu, it still give me the same error

Comment: My test on CMD is : **N5110A11.exe /forceit**

Comment: Try `N5110A11.exe -forceit` and `N5110A11.exe forceit`.

Comment: According to [Dell](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln137741/forcing-a-bios-update-without-the-ac-adapter-attached-on-a-dell-laptop?lang=en), the correct switch is `/forceit`. Are you running the command from an elevated command prompt? If so, redownload the BIOS update, verify the checksum value and try again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [/forceit in Command Prompt Gives error: unknown command](https://superuser.com/questions/889622/forceit-in-command-prompt-gives-error-unknown-command)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same symptoms you described:  Running `N5110A11.exe /FORCEIT` in Windows on a Dell Inspiron N5110 failed with "unknown command".  The solution which worked for me was from https://superuser.com/a/1386926:

1. Create a bootable USB stick by choosing "[FreeDOS](https://www.freedos.org/)" from the "boot selection" options in [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/).
2. Copy `N5110A11.exe` to the USB stick.
3. Reboot and repeatedly press `F12` to enter the BIOS boot menu.
4. Boot from the USB stick.
5. Run `N5110A11.exe /FORCEIT`.

The command worked for me when run from DOS mode.